# Enable UITableViewCell with its own view and data

Tags: ios, xcode, swift

So i have a tableview with the possibility to add a new item to the main tableView view. In my example:

The user enters the app. There are 5 items presented in a tableView.
The user selects one of those items. Those items are as follow:

- Trip to NYC
- Trip to Cali
- Trip to Tokyo
- Trip to Spain
- Trip to London

**The Problem:**
So the user enters "Trip to Cali", thus presenting a viewController but the user needs to add some text to this view inside a UITextfield box. So once the user enters this text, he or she can go back through the navigation bar and this data saves.

So the user then chooses "Trip to Spain" and the user is presented with the same view but a clean slate to write some text and save it.

So in other words, i am trying to think of this like an Associative array where each of those objects holds their own kind of data.

Below this is the structure of the Object that is used to tap on those items mentioned:

```
import Foundation

class Item: NSObject, NSCoding { //comforming to the NSCoding protocol

    var title = ""


    func encodeWithCoder(aCoder: NSCoder) {

        aCoder.encodeObject(course, forKey: "title")


    }

    required init(coder aDecoder: NSCoder) {

        title = aDecoder.decodeObjectForKey("title") as! String

        super.init()
    }

    override init() {
        super.init()
    }
}
```

How would i go about achieving this?

Comment: Not really understanding what you want to do, but the simplest way to store data is using NSUserDefaults. You could store the text entered like this:
`NSUserDefaults.standardUserDefaults().setValue(enteredText, forKey: tripToCityName)`

Comment: I am trying to save data to each of those items. Like the contacts app in in your iPhone. You enter a new contact, and within that contact, you set up data for itself. that data is different than the data from other contacts. Thats at its simplest form of what i am trying to achieve

Comment: Looks like you just need to add another variable to the Item class shown above, right after title. var comments = "" or something like that.

Comment: As I said before, the simplest way of storing data is NSUserDefaults. You can store any type of object in it. It's not the recommended way to do so, if you have the need to query through your data in some point of your app, or if you have large amounts of data.